Calculated property with filtering pagination Spring Boot
I have a question for you. Must be easy solution for this. I'm trying to make filter by 'result', I mean I have a class Calculation and a lot of subclasses for example entity Multiplication, Sum, Division itd.
//lombok
@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
public abstract class Calculation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

}

//lombok
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("SUM")
public class Sum extends Calculation {

    private double firstNumber;
    private double secondNumber;

}


itd.
I want to have in my service class pagination with filtering BY RESULT.
I mean if we have in SUM (2 and 3) i want to have somewhere RESULT of this.
    @Override
    public Page<CalculationDto> findAll(Criteria criteria, Pageable pageable) {
        Specification<Calculation> specification = Specification.SpecificationBuilder
                .withResult(criteria.getResult())
                .build();

        return calculationRepository.findAll(specification, pageable)
                .map(CalculationFacade::mapToDto)
                .toList();
    }

And the question is how to do something like this. I was trying do this with @Formula, but it wasnt working for me properly (maybe i was doing this wrong). Maybe i shouldn't use SINGLE_TABLE idk. I just need an idea and a little help.
I want to filter by RESULT of calculation.
